# Is it possible to add hatches to each individual bar in seaborn.barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, bar-chart, seaborn

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="size", y="algorithm", hue="ordering", data=df2, palette=sns.color_palette("cubehelix", 4))
```

After (or before) creating a seaborn barplot, is there a way for me to pass in hatch (fill in patterns along with the colors) values for each bar? 
A way to do this in `seaborn` or `matplotlib` would help a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "each individual bar". Do you mean you want every bar to have hatches, or you want different bars to have different hatches?

Comment: @mwaskom Thanks for the reply! I need different bars to have different hatches. You can set all bars to have the same hatch by just passing `hatch='//'` in sns.barplot. No idea how to have different hatches in different bars though..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can loop over the bars created by catching the `AxesSubplot` returned by `barplot`, then looping over its `patches`. You can then set hatches for each individual bar using `.set_hatch()`

Here's a minimal example, which is a modified version of the barplot example from [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html#bar-plots).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Set style
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

# Load some sample data
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Make the barplot
bar = sns.barplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=titanic);

# Define some hatches
hatches = ['-', '+', 'x', '\\', '*', 'o']

# Loop over the bars
for i,thisbar in enumerate(bar.patches):
    # Set a different hatch for each bar
    thisbar.set_hatch(hatches[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks to @kxirog in the comments for this additional info:

`for i,thisbar in enumerate(bar.patches)` will iterate over each colour at a time from left to right, so it will iterate over the left blue bar, then the right blue bar, then the left green bar, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for! Do you think there is a way to add the hatches to the legend as well?

Comment: Just as so every one knows, because it took me a bit to figure it out: `for i,thisbar in enumerate(bar.patches):` iterates over each color at a time fron left to right, so it will iterate over the left blue bar, then the right blue bar, then the left green bar etc...

Comment: @kxirog Just put `ax.legend()` after adding the hatches and before `plt.show()`.

Comment: For `box = sns.boxplot` use `box.artists` instead of `.patches`.

Comment: For `hist = sns.histplot` use `hist.collections` instead of `.patches` (at least for `element='step'`)

Comment: To get the legende accordingly try to iterate over `reversed(hist.legend_.legendHandles)` (at least for my histplot).

Answer (score 1):

Hatches can be added to most polygons in `Matplotlib`, including `bar`, `fill_between`, `contourf`, and children of `Polygon`.

[Hash demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_demo.html)

[Hatch style reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html#)

Hash styles:

```
hatches = ['/', '\\', '|', '-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*']
hatches = ['//', '\\\\', '||', '--', '++', 'xx', 'oo', 'OO', '..', '**']
hatches = ['/o', '\\|', '|*', '-\\', '+o', 'x*', 'o-', 'O|', 'O.', '*-']
```

Sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.25  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men', hatch="//")
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women', hatch="++")

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]