# seaborn barplot padding between bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Shortly ago, I posted this question:
[seaborn barplot: vary color with x and hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257550/seaborn-barplot-vary-color-with-x-and-hue/58257672#58257672)

My sample code from that question produces a barplot, which looks like this:

[image: barplot spaced]

As you can see, there is a very tiny space between the bars.

The code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["model", "time", "value"])
df["model"] = ["on"]*2 + ["off"]*2
df["time"] = ["short", "long"] * 2
df["value"] = [1, 10, 2, 4]

sns.barplot(data=df, x="model", hue="time", y="value")
plt.show()
```

Now I executed the code on a different machine and it produced a different image:
[image: barplot unspaced]

The different colors are no concern, I'll specify my own palette in any case. But an important difference for me is: The bars touch each other now, there is no longer a white border between them.

How can I reproduce the original behaviour, how can I explicitly set the padding of barplots bars in seaborn ?

My current seaborn version is 0.9.0. Unfortunately, I don't know with which version the original image was created.

Comment: `edgecolor="white"`?

Comment: yes, that fixes it. Thanks. Could you convert the comment into an answer, so that I can accept it ?